# Does an incomplete update affect my programs?

Tags: upgrade

I saw a pop up which said 'updates are available' so I clicked it. I completely forgot that the installation was incomplete, I logged off. NOw when I came back, it told me to do a partial update. I read the internet for information, partial update wasn't the safest thing for me. I tried to log in to skype, it said another skype may exist. That wasn't true, Skype wasn't opened. I'm not sure if it's because of the incomplete update, but I'm quite off, in trouble. Please reply. Thank you

Regards
Junior

Answer (score 2):

It depends to what phase of the update you were on, If it was just downloading, Its fairly safe

If its installing, a `sudo apt-get -f install` will fix it in most cases, but sometimes it does not work